# How to type check i18n dictionaries with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, i18next, react-i18next

Is there a possibility to type check existing keys in [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/) dictionaries? So that TS will warn you during compile time if key doesn't exist.

Example.

Suppose, we have this dictionary:

```
{
  "footer": {
    "copyright": "Some copyrights"
  },

  "header": {
    "logo": "Logo",
    "link": "Link",
  },
}
```

If I provide non-existent key, TS should blow up:

```
const { t } = useTranslation();

<span> { t('footer.copyright') } </span> // this is OK, because footer.copyright exists
<span> { t('footer.logo') } </span> // TS BOOM!! there is no footer.logo in dictionary
```

What is the proper name of this technique? I'm very sure I'm not the only one who is asking for this behavior.

Is it implemented in `react-i18next` out of the box? 
Are there API in `react-i18next` to extend the library somehow to enable it? I want to avoid creating wrapper functions.

Answer (score 44):

## TS 4.1

finally [supports](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/) typed string-key lookups and interpolation via [template literal types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336).

We now can use a dotted string argument to access dictionary keys / the object path deeply:

```
t("footer"); // ✅ { copyright: "Some copyrights"; }
t("footer.copyright"); // ✅ "Some copyrights"
t("footer.logo"); // ❌ should trigger compile error
```

Let's look **1.)** at a suitable return type for a translate function `t`  **2.)** how we can emit a compile error on non-matching key arguments and provide IntelliSense **3.)** at an example of string interpolation.

### 1. Key lookup: return type

```
// returns property value from object O given property path T, otherwise never
type GetDictValue<T extends string, O> =
    T extends `${infer A}.${infer B}` ? 
    A extends keyof O ? GetDictValue<B, O[A]> : never
    : T extends keyof O ? O[T] : never

function t<P extends string>(p: P): GetDictValue<P, typeof dict> { /* impl */ }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgS2LAvDA3gKBjmAiAMxBCgFMAnPALg213r1AAcBPchAcwAspr8BlEAFtSMZm048IeOjgC+AGln4upAIZwKfLPQYAbEBxB88AGUPGlu3Hj0IwAaxOn7Tq7kWY5MNRDHhoGAB6IJgAQT0ycjA1KAQAN1IaPXVEmBAAV1gAA19-SChsoM1gPTVyUShVGCgWJlFSAA8mO2AEMj0WTEwQmAqoDOi-KtEmchB68lqYeLU9DNECcaF0gCMAK1JkGAB5GA4E0jAYMYmKaaZYrhgAFUxa+pgAcVIoABEkKAA1OYWAHhuMCaZDAcD80HYYA4Cl2AD4YChlIDgUcwTBsgASdD2AgUcJyAB0WJxeIAQnJsjAAPwwZRhIGNEFohykFggAi7anPV4fZA-eakP6kmE7ADaYQAuvCaGBSIlyMoaMjGai-Cy2Ry9jSxTcJTAZXKKN0HqIbgBGBHc96ffn-QjEKIE8Tsbi8GEm9nwT7w3rmy14QQifysF1SGQm24AJktL2tfN+gvtJAoBIMRjw7rqpE9iGQPtCN2jaFl8u6vQQQhapBEYCgsQQ4HSQnaZDgMFUFUwJTKFRgBAyYGQDeOUD+AAUGUzwVBIRxYQAKJg0McAShosd53wT48z9Rz3uN86TUTwK4A3MFQoBQcgwfXUcHAnWDEldNADwlEzskUGkF7k9yPIhk3IJ0JhfHhTwvXob3fIMv1daQAOPFM02Mc9LxgQAZchgEsKCAA)

### 2. Key lookup: IntelliSense and compile errors

It might be sufficient to just trigger compile errors on wrong keys:

```
// returns the same string literal T, if props match, else never
type CheckDictString<T extends string, O> =
  T extends `${infer A}.${infer B}` ?
  A extends keyof O ? `${A}.${Extract<CheckDictString<B, O[A]>, string>}` :never
  : T extends keyof O ? T : never

function t<P extends string>(p: CheckDictString<P, typeof dict>)
  : GetDictValue<P, typeof dict> { /* impl */ }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgS2LAvDA3gKBjmAiAMxBCgFMAnPALg213r1AAcBPchAcwAspr8BlEAFtSMZm048IeOjgC+AGln4upAIZwKfLPQYAbEBxB88AGUPGlu3Hj0IwAaxOn7Tq7kWY5MNRDHhoGAB6IJgAQT0ycjA1KAQAN1IaPXVEmBAAV1gAA19-SChsoM1gPTVyUShVGCgWJlFSAA8mO2AEMj0WTEwQmAqoDOi-KtEmchB68lqYeLU9DNECcaF0gCMAK1JkGAB5GA4E0jAYMYmKaaZYrhgAFUxa+pgAcVIoABEkKAA1OYWAHhuMCaZDAcD80HYYA4Cl2AD4YChlIDgUcwTBsgASdD2AgUcJyAB0WJxeIAQnJsjAAPzhIGNEFohykFggAi7anPV4fZA-eakP6kmE7ADaYQAuvCaGBSIlyMoaMj6ai-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-Kirq38uOqgCZCgTKJPgqS8G63pABlyIFyHGcggA)

Read on, if you also want [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense).
Following type will query all possible key path permutations of the dictionary, provide auto complete and assist with error hints for non-matching keys:

```
// get all possible key paths
type DeepKeys<T> = T extends object ? {
    [K in keyof T]-?: `${K & string}` | Concat<K & string, DeepKeys<T[K]>>
}[keyof T] : ""

// or: only get leaf and no intermediate key path
type DeepLeafKeys<T> = T extends object ?
    { [K in keyof T]-?: Concat<K & string, DeepKeys<T[K]>> }[keyof T] : "";

type Concat<K extends string, P extends string> =
    `${K}${"" extends P ? "" : "."}${P}`
```

```
function t<P extends DeepKeys<typeof dict>>(p: P) : GetDictValue<P, typeof dict> 
  { /* impl */ } 

type T1 = DeepKeys<typeof dict> 
// "footer" | "header" | "footer.copyright" | "header.logo" | "header.link"
type T2 = DeepLeafKeys<typeof dict> 
// "footer.copyright" | "header.logo" | "header.link"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgS2LAvDA3gKBjmAiAMxBCgFMAnPALg213r1AAcBPchAcwAspr8BlEAFtSMZm048IeOjgC%20AGln4upAIZwKfLPQYAbEBxB88AGUPGlu3Hj0IwAaxOn7Tq7kWY5MNRDHhoGExMKBYmUQBxUigAESQoADU1PQBXUgAeABUYUgAPMjA4P2h2MA4FGAB5AD4YFGVsvIKimAADABJ0ewIKGABBOQA6Tu7egCE5VpgAfn6c-NJCvwdSFhACKpmYKNj4pNSMsYrKgG0%20gF1amjBSADcKZRpGhaWYFbWNyq3TzPOYa7uD0wmmAejU5FEBBSYGQCHAMCg6QACvNmn4YqRSEwANKrCDpULhdbweLVaoACiYNCRAEoaDs4sh9mlkRVCaRiYhkNVguyYBisbiWPjMrU0M80TAQAAjABWpGQWx0uBO2Jg9jeq2JvwAtNMaB10GqAGQwEr2DiTGAAHxgAGFwMA1IiTWaoKVyvzMTi8VlVZceXITu9tX8aHgZCEwqIBUxTOoCEKRWKYBLFi0ZfLFdNlOgYKr1WBNR9U%20c9TQHTDnelXeayhVY0m-diAzAgyGNr9-vg8ABuXnR%202O6tqprp4rui0VFFj151jhi5SG7FyToR1HjmAo2br8ODPCr9BIyYD8KpgCMdS9gt97M5pJgAHpH-giCQtDaVOpNJRP4RiGQ5CDOI7DcLwf6qBoFCDAYRh4BB37QXYjgyHymQAExXrG8ZqImt7Rve3JPi%20-7vkBIGSOBtp4JBP4wRY8HUbRSGuJGz4wAAkmAZB6HY-CLBAogQCkHAcKQ0BwpAPiFP4QhMAgeiiBQ5AgOQEAAIQhOSpGAXgNK9kEUDaW%20gHASArCgTwekGVpOlIQx%20kwEAA)

See [Typescript: deep keyof of a nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object) for more details.

Due to combinatory complexity and depending on dictionary object shape, you might hit compiler [recursion](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#recursive-conditional-types) depth limits. A more lightweight alternative: provide IntelliSense for the *next* key path incrementally based on *current* input:

```
// T is the dictionary, S ist the next string part of the object property path
// If S does not match dict shape, return its next expected properties 
type DeepKeys<T, S extends string> =
    T extends object
    ? S extends `${infer I1}.${infer I2}`
        ? I1 extends keyof T
            // fix issue allowed last dot
            ? T[I1] extends object
                ? `${I1}.${DeepKeys<T[I1], I2>}`
                : keyof T & string
            : keyof T & string
        : S extends keyof T
            ? `${S}`
            : keyof T & string
    : ""

function t<S extends string>(p: DeepKeys<typeof dict, S>)
  : GetDictValue<S, typeof dict> { /* impl */ }

// IntelliSense suggestions and compile errors!
// Press Ctrl+Space just outside the string, inside parentheses
t("f"); // error, suggests "footer" | "header"
t("footer"); // OK
t("footer."); // error, suggests "footer.copyright"
t("footer.copyright"); // OK
t("header.") // error, suggests "header.logo" | "header.link"
t("footer.copyright."); // error, suggests "footer.copyright"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgS2LAvDA3gKBjmAzEEKAUwCcAuDbXG0ABwE9SEBzACykoCIBlEAW2Ix6TVhwhdqOAL4AaKTDbEAhnDKUsNGgBsQLENwAyekF3lbc2hGADWR6zbMK5maTGURh4aJkxrg2sqkQngArmDICOAwUAA8PDDEAB4kYHCe0MxgLAB8ABR0lAAixMR0ANLEDBCxUAx0xCB48EhQsjA8OQCUlADixFBFrQBqytqhxPHtdQ1NLcg5vjNC-YMjYxOxACqJKcRpGVBZLO0A8jkwKAo7yanpMAAGACTo1nhkMACC0gB0L28fABC0geMAA-F9dndPDYqnNTuCYKshshRuNJoCzgBtT4AXQulDAxAAbmQFJQbnsDjBYQx4YjTlitriYISSWTMAB6TkwHYITxQJTzKBRMBBBjtBL82CCoRElIwTLWFgwOhBWBzWUwEAAIwAVsRkKrSCAGqQ6qrlIKuTyAJLNBJwEDETxgIgwfhW4BsYWKtjKBrtYJQUKkMAwBBQV23XYNZDEODG01kEUumCYZYwEplSrVbaSqH7e5K7IXK40SnQ7X6w1QBQQhK3IueZ6vMDvUgwW0ARl+-3bH1tACYQQoaBCe4XqbS5lsxxYYNz8AgkhGIBAJu5tLoAO4JmCBaDwIjziwQrZYnsspvU3UG5Cnhc4CGtnt99DZipVGoXq-tYc5KOT5PpQM7NDsABkipHMqj40KBcLgTAUEliwj6UI2VL3GBvJwbgL4vDwQHATgCF0khKEwdk5IwFwkgZvUQhbN2lxZqUX55sscyIMg7R0RcS5cAQRBkFwMAAD60UoqiiQxDS8kOrGfrmNRcc0PFtLReBcAJPJCYQJCkGJklcNJahGXJTEAMxKexKm1Ix3GtHxwmGTpi56a5smZlsAAstk5t+DmzOpzlaQZZA-O5gleaQPwiMw7BQJIPkAKwBRxqmOaFvFSSo5lRbpeUyXFuj6MZxUFVYtj0UutpgCQ24IDw+wQEIG4sCwLoit47hpF4-B0Ag2hCGQJqkBAACENowAACsE64wAAwkc2gANQ8GqwBCHqoRHiAoRRggagxEKqHtNYEDHUIarBA1ShtRAGZ5EJXBdAA3B5iSkON7QdV10CePpIlGRJlXeS9sVvZ9S6nOUz3A4ZUUfV9Y0gKQf2hJ13VA7F8WmqISUpZDEVxQlYjJSjsPw1AL1mZFb2oz96OY9jgPg6VJgVaZ+WRdVjgI3j5NJcjMM8mjGOKljANRuFIP44wiUcFwQA)

### 3. Interpolation

Here is an example making use of [string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation) [interpolation](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation).

```
// retrieves all variable placeholder names as tuple
type Keys<S extends string> = S extends '' ? [] :
    S extends `${infer _}{{${infer B}}}${infer C}` ? [B, ...Keys<C>] : never

// substitutes placeholder variables with input values
type Interpolate<S extends string, I extends Record<Keys<S>[number], string>> =
    S extends '' ? '' :
    S extends `${infer A}{{${infer B}}}${infer C}` ?
    `${A}${I[Extract<B, keyof I>]}${Interpolate<C, I>}`
    : never
```

##### Example:

```
type Dict = { "key": "yeah, {{what}} is {{how}}" }
type KeysDict = Keys<Dict["key"]> // type KeysDict = ["what", "how"]
type I1 = Interpolate<Dict["key"], { what: 'i18next', how: 'great' }>;
// type I1 = "yeah, i18next is great"

function t<
    K extends keyof Dict,
    I extends Record<Keys<Dict[K]>[number], string>
>(k: K, args: I): Interpolate<Dict[K], I> { /* impl */ }

const ret = t('key', { what: 'i18next', how: 'great' } as const);
// const ret: "yeah, i18next is great"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECcFMBdwS0gN0gZ1AQwDadI990AjTSUAB03QGNIALAe0wBNJxQA7dAW1QzWgCuFSAChoATzKkA0pHEoAPAGVQkAB7RI7JmhSw47AOYA+UAF5QK9Zu1oA5HdAB+UAG0AuqABcI0H8uqGlo6oAAGACQA3gYAZqygAPoAvpGRUbHxAEJJOenscWwAwkmhzm6ZADSgAHS1svIKhcaeXhxIrCIiIKAoAoR6cIKaaBTUdIwsbHgExLwA7oO0oAZkAtC4WAKoYpKkAJLsmuBkjOiayoE2IXrwRlV7l8FoAEqQVPTgTAr1ikrGruwBFxCKx3FUbgYTKYzL5-FYgrZQA4ysifP4AtYnmE8gVQABBFJpaL5LI5JI4+LFUpOWF+CKRAlRPauACiGnA1GgCkqoAA1nJ6DFQHtmuTIgcjidKOdCvdjCVad42shwJ1umzuMIdlJQAAROBUdYWSKgABE-PEptapvEkHQtCqqTmtDOOWWaFSDDmOVNoCS2pkchQ+sN5lAPwUIegrnNclN7lM3QkOp+UbDMedZ1NVVNXvjAeFAEYwxLWFKzpBIwbo7HLWDQCbM9BWnY4IWABzsax2KpeluGKBnRxJYwAbi6YGT+2LFhtdodyw7XY07tAA7t0FNarAcC4wh4hzOcHo7FA9C4g00TFAtFYohYVEoUFAMQE7ENx9PXMV0keiItgp6tWFSKg8mKIq87yfN8QZVoarjSAmAJAiC4D1hCRjGCIxgABS8q00hVPghgoK0ewAJRkYcZanOcUYIfWIqdO87B6BAMBhtAOF2BaPYNk2LZtp23a9vQcz9oO0B2EkfCgCxejkeO3TyesUDNmatr2lUQnLuscBoOuWZAA)

<sup>Note: All snippets can be used in combination with `react-i18next` or independently.</sup>

---

---

## Old answer

(**PRE TS 4.1**) There are two reasons why strong typed keys are not possible in `react-i18next`:

1.) TypeScript has no way to evaluate [dynamic or computed string expressions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579) like `'footer.copyright'`, so that `footer` and `copyright` could be identified as key parts in the translations object hierarchy.

2.) [`useTranslation`](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/364653c/src/index.d.ts#L55-L63) does [not enforce](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/2dede04/index.d.ts#L655-L675) type constraints to your defined dictionary/translations. Instead function `t` contains generic type parameters defaulting to `string`, when not manually specified.

---

Here is an alternative solution that makes use of [Rest parameters/tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types).

##### Typed `t` function:

```
type Dictionary = string | DictionaryObject;
type DictionaryObject = { [K: string]: Dictionary };

interface TypedTFunction<D extends Dictionary> {
    <K extends keyof D>(args: K): D[K];
    <K extends keyof D, K1 extends keyof D[K]>(...args: [K, K1]): D[K][K1];
    <K extends keyof D, K1 extends keyof D[K], K2 extends keyof D[K][K1]>(
        ...args: [K, K1, K2]
    ): D[K][K1][K2];
    // ... up to a reasonable key parameters length of your choice ...
}
```

##### Typed `useTranslation` Hook:

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

type MyTranslations = {/* your concrete type*/}
// e.g. via const dict = {...}; export type MyTranslations = typeof dict

// import this hook in other modules instead of i18next useTranslation
export function useTypedTranslation(): { t: TypedTFunction<typeof dict> } {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  // implementation goes here: join keys by dot (depends on your config)
  // and delegate to lib t
  return { t(...keys: string[]) { return t(keys.join(".")) } }  
}
```

##### Import `useTypedTranslation` in other modules:

```
import { useTypedTranslation } from "./useTypedTranslation"

const App = () => {
  const { t } = useTypedTranslation()
  return <div>{t("footer", "copyright")}</div>
}
```

##### Test it:

```
const res1 = t("footer"); // const res1: { "copyright": string;}
const res2 = t("footer", "copyright"); // const res2: string
const res3 = t("footer", "copyright", "lala"); // error, OK
const res4 = t("lala"); // error, OK
const res5 = t("footer", "lala"); // error, OK
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wCgB6cuECNAazk2jgBtgAjRgVwDsNgIPUgBMkaFiiJw0ggM7wuspABUoKHrIkwBPAFxwAFAEo4AXgB8cAN5wY+gGK9+guAF9SpGRvjDgGM9akcMGMEBAwSFD6VkEhcTJgAJ5QwADmABZ2BADKuEjSEEkpGTCyZHGuADQecemoolGBcXEsEKkQ+vgAMm0Q+NXNIWw8dJ1dwCPlIe6uANweMIlg+QAiftqCkokB8ik8qXAAPnBrzjxbAPLsAFZiMPOLyyfrOpc3dwE2ANoA0vq7E1SAF19KcNucoNs5h4JhEoJh0PllEskMJlI4+OCADwrOBIAAeER4wlkzzOW0sMTiWJ+eMJSGJpLoSESEEwJ3MBkkqVk+h+RlBvyB82ptIJRJJcGZrPZK0qcB+AEY6RKmSy2SchZyAHS67m8uC-eVKoECzU-IG-RXC2LBGkqhmS6UauUK5Xix1qmXmoHGgBMDsZUvVsqFVqBnNtzV12v1+iNbv9QKjZpWYZNvz9NrilDgMbgXDAtggcBQcCIKFkm3YLHy0rgYEkKBASDhpNr+xg6TgGtZXCg0nSED8+RjpHcpAJkFg3ExOgLSmRyzRag0Wh0xmitn0S9R6Kc2MeSA1vgwllcTRCXnk1lsbgCihUq80KHBxhFIVzoDAtZbPBgr7zu0SCknURDanAAASkT5Ncw48MGiSkuw2zCOEhiiMsQYuH2A6FOCshGFGRAwP2CE2DABgxtKBoAvsXymreJFkbYBg0dqcETAY+DavgRgmBeMweFO0DwNe8AUfepgLioKIruoL5vkY8yeHI8BELIyrSZR+BMOEkR8bMcC5uJ5YgYqW74AkyRpJk+D-DAeypLM7imRpAbadxelwv0BDWcUdnKcZVBuSBfoOU5qneGZsgAMwBDp3kGfKVmFDZJS+fgEgSIZwV4lAOBQPKFw-FFN4aQALAl3HZSguW5pEhXFaVoWyAArNVulhD5KW1fVVCNdAzUeGV8AAIJgEW0nGGYlhYr4ABu5hWIl3XJX5aUBTAfGuFi5CLeYQA)

You potentially could [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) those types automatically instead of the multiple overload signatures ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-QHiWmYLD4YjsqBILAjBoIMIIogCkV2UK9CKBfQ8PQBtJ6JqAPSdmDF6AwMsVyjweIyxIAbh4fdL5YATFXWbXyvXkI30WwW22yB2YN3e+B+4PZ-mEUYgA)). Be aware that these [recursive types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050) are [not recommended for production](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897#issuecomment-401418254) by core developers [till TS 4.1](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002).

Comment: I was talking about i18n interpolation like `i18next.t('key', { what: 'i18next', how: 'great' });`. check here https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation

Comment: @VarunSukheja updated answer with interpolation

Comment: Is it possible to have intellisense with this?

Comment: @YassineBridi good suggestion. Updated answer with a section on IntelliSense.

Comment: how about loading the json from a file?

Comment: understand nothing (now i realized that i dont know nothing about TS ) congrats on the answer!

Comment: @Rafo This is probably one of the more advanced concepts, hence no worries (-: . Most of the useful stuff in TS only needs basic knowledge.

Comment: Use `const value = t(keyName as (keyof Dict));` to get value of variable key.

Comment: Since **typescript 4.7.4** (maybe 4.7) the recursive solution of **2. Key lookup** doesn't work correctly with IntelliSense anymore, the best solution is, therefore, the previous one, the one with `DeepLeafKeys`. This can be seen in the playground, switching between v4.6.4 and v4.7.4

Answer (score 25):

React-i18next now has built-in support for this. I couldn't find official documentation, but there are helpful comments in the [source code](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/v11.8.4/src/ts4.1/index.d.ts#L23).

Assuming your translations are in `public/locales/[locale]/translation.json` and your primary language is English:

```js
// src/i18n-resources.d.ts

import 'react-i18next'

declare module 'react-i18next' {
  export interface Resources {
    translation: typeof import('../public/locales/en/translation.json')
  }
}
```

If you're using [multiple translation files](https://react.i18next.com/guides/multiple-translation-files) you'll need to add them all to the Resources interface, keyed by namespace.

Make sure to set `"resolveJsonModule": true` in your `tsconfig.json` if you're importing the translations from a json file.

Comment: For anyone on `react-i18next` versions higher than 11.11.0 and you're following https://react.i18next.com/latest/typescript, and you're getting the issue of `Module '"react-i18next"' has no exported member 'initReactI18next'.` or `Module '"react-i18next"' has no exported member 'useTranslations'.` (any import name really), all you need to do to fix this is rename your type file from `react-i18next.d.ts` to `i18n-resources.d.ts` as this answer shows. The file name the documentation shows appears to break merging, renaming will fix and keep your typing.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achive this behavior is to generate the TranslationKey type and use it than in useT hook and custom Trans component.

1. create translation.json file

```
{
  "PAGE_TITLE": "Product Status",
  "TABLES": {
    "COUNTRY": "Country",
    "NO_DATA_AVAILABLE": "No price data available"
  }
}
```

2. generate type TranslationKey with generateTranslationTypes.js

````
/**
 * This script generates the TranslationKey.ts types that are used from
 * useT and T components
 *
 * to generate type run this command
 *
 * ```
 * node src/i18n/generateTranslationTypes.js
 * ```
 *
 * or
 * ```
 * npm run generate-translation-types
 * ```
 */

/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const translation = require("./translation.json")
const fs = require("fs")
// console.log("translation", translation)

function extractKeys(obj, keyPrefix = "", separator = ".") {
  const combinedKeys = []
  const keys = Object.keys(obj)

  keys.forEach(key => {
    if (typeof obj[key] === "string") {
      if (key.includes("_plural")) {
        return
      }
      combinedKeys.push(keyPrefix + key)
    } else {
      combinedKeys.push(...extractKeys(obj[key], keyPrefix + key + separator))
    }
  })

  return combinedKeys
}

function saveTypes(types) {
  const content = `// generated file by src/i18n/generateTranslationTypes.js

type TranslationKey =
${types.map(type => `  | "${type}"`).join("\n")}
`
  fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/TranslationKey.ts", content, "utf8", function(
    err
  ) {
    if (err) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log("An error occurred while writing to File.")
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      return console.log(err)
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log("file has been saved.")
  })
}

const types = extractKeys(translation)

// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
console.log("types: ", types)

saveTypes(types)
````

3. useT hook similar to useTranslation that uses TranslationKey type

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next"
import { TOptions, StringMap } from "i18next"

function useT<TInterpolationMap extends object = StringMap>() {
  const { t } = useTranslation()
  return {
    t(key: TranslationKey, options?: TOptions<TInterpolationMap> | string) {
      return t(key, options)
    },
  }
}

export default useT
```

4. T component similar to Trans component

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react"
import useT from "./useT"
import { TOptions, StringMap } from "i18next"

export interface Props<TInterpolationMap extends object = StringMap> {
  id: TranslationKey
  options?: TOptions<TInterpolationMap> | string
  tag?: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | typeof Fragment
}

export function T<TInterpolationMap extends object = StringMap>({
  id,
  options,
  tag = Fragment,
}: Props<TInterpolationMap>) {
  const { t } = useT()
  const Wrapper = tag as "div"
  return <Wrapper>{t(id, options)}</Wrapper>
}

export default T
```

5. use useT and T with type checked ids

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const { t } = useT()


    return (
        <div>
            { t("PAGE_TITLE", {count: 1})}
            <T id="TABLES.COUNTRY" options={{count: 1}} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The official documentation explains how to achieve type safety: https://www.i18next.com/overview/typescript

E.g.

```
// import the original type declarations
import "i18next";
// import all namespaces (for the default language, only)
import ns1 from "locales/en/ns1.json";
import ns2 from "locales/en/ns2.json";

declare module "i18next" {
  // Extend CustomTypeOptions
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    // custom namespace type, if you changed it
    defaultNS: "ns1";
    // custom resources type
    resources: {
      ns1: typeof ns1;
      ns2: typeof ns2;
    };
    // other
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Great answer @ford04, but has a little trouble on Keys and Interpolate type, if you use in this way and don't have a variable in the end of string, the interpolate will not identify it. To resolve this problem, can be did this way:

```
export type Keys<S extends string> =
  S extends `${string}{{${infer B}}}${infer C}`
    ? C extends `${string}{{${string}}}${string}`
      ? [B, ...Keys<C>]
      : [B]
    : never;
```

```
type Interpolate<
  S extends string,
  I extends Record<Keys<S>[number], string>,
> = S extends ''
  ? ''
  : S extends `${infer A}{{${infer B}}}${infer C}`
  ? C extends `${string}{{${string}}}${string}`
    ? `${A}${I[Extract<B, keyof I>]}${Interpolate<C, I>}`
    : `${A}${I[Extract<B, keyof I>]}`
  : never;
```

Follow the example: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=48&pln=20&pc=58#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBBpEyDOAeAZQXDhADsATHBHOGASzIHMA%20BAXmAQSJPKoQADACQBvWg2YBfUaLGMAZiBgIAQlI3yySlQGEpgrtwQB%20BLuJhSlaiPF1GTGXPuSnm144NHjphAG1VABoEADpwrFw8XRYAXR9jAC4A1XjfZLIQADdlAG5gYBQ0BABJMlIYaAAbAENSPCNeK35qCUcgoxLLawEAJRAAY1gKPEj8AhZ-MgBXAFsAI2VYkLbmFg62dh5uloQAcj2jMwOjZKae2y0dBABBZyvlNQ0pB71vbjMLPhshMVWnWR-BzSDz-d7GMx2O5iEr%20ACiVhgNQGcDwwQQAGtsFAFKU4i9RGUKtU6iBoiESixwdxklCCbCEXRkaj0VjkDi8bECfpDDSEJkcjB8oVUOgACL0FEcBCiTHYZJ7ZAgGoACxCsgA7iq6hoEPRqLIVVANRoQjV5jgoFVpnAalVkHsEFJ8kV0GMJVKtmM8B64P49my9rEWLkEAB6MNIUWYbA4X3S-wAIi1dUTIUTRo1ifirtKAEZpUTlCT6r7-YHljKECm4Ar6HmAByZKx7UOZhVMGDKuCOqQh4BAA)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a cli that supports the generation of dts type definition files from multiple json configurations. You can try it. At present, the advanced types of ts 4 have not yet fully supported the features of i18next, so I chose code generation.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@liuli-util/i18next-dts-gen

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution witch gets the key (also nested keys) from a dictionary.

```
declare module 'i18next' {
    import deTranslation from 'path/to/dictionary.json';

    type Translations<T = typeof deTranslation> = T;
    type ConcatKeys<T, U> = T extends string ? `${T & string}.${U & string}` : never;

    // Define a recursive type for nested keys
    type NestedKeys<T> =
        T extends object ? {
                [K in keyof T]: K | ConcatKeys<K, NestedKeys<T[K]>>;
            }[keyof T] :
            string;

    type TranslationKeys<T> = NestedKeys<T>;
    interface TranslationFunction<T> {
        <K extends TranslationKeys<T>>(key: K, nestedKeys?: string[]): string;
    }
    export const t: TranslationFunction<Translations>;
}
```

With that you get suggestions and validation.
[image]