# react-i18next and typescript 4.1

Tags: reactjs, typescript, i18next, react-i18next

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use react-i18next with typescript 4.1.

According to the docs, I should be able to do:

```
const { t } = useTranslation();
return <h1>{t('title')}</h1>
```

However, that call to `t` errors:

```
No overload matches this call: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

What does work is using either:

`useTranslation<string>()`

or

`useTranslation('translation')`

Both of these seem unnecessary qualifications.

This seems to only be the case with typescript 4, as if I downgrade to typescript 3 the error goes away.

Is there a way to use the shorter `useTranslation()` in typescript 4?

Comment: did you see this ?? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58277973/how-to-type-check-i18n-dictionaries-with-typescript

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the latest release of react-i18next. See [#1213 (typescript) Template literals no longer work post 11.8.0](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/1213)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is probably late, but there is very good boilerPlate for starting react typescript i18next app.
Check this github - https://github.com/Lemoncode/i18next-example-typescript